# How many real-valued functions with one point of discontinuity are there?

Tags: cardinals

I was given the following task:

> Find the cardinality of the set $C$ of real-valued functions with *exactly* one point of discontinuity.

What I've found so far is that
$$
\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert \le \lvert C \rvert
$$
because the map $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to C$ defined as
$$
f(x_0) := x \mapsto \frac{1}{x-x_0}
$$
is injective.

Now, can I prove that $\lvert C \rvert \le \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$?

I'd like to apply the [Schroeder-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) theorem. However, I don't know how to proceed. Should I take the same approach as in finding the cardinality of the set of continuous real-valued functions, and find a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\lbrace x_0 \rbrace$?

---

P.s.: After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594235/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-real-functions-which-have-a-countable-set-of-disco?rq=1), and confronting it with the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2133286/124708) given by @Arthur, I'm trying to do the following:

1. Choose a point of discontinuity $x_0$;
2. Choosing two continuous functions on $(-\infty,x_0)$ and $(x_0,+\infty)$, which can be done by taking their restrictions on the dense subsets $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\infty,x_0)$ and $\mathbb{Q} \cap (x_0,+\infty)$;
3. Choose a function value for $x_0$, i.e. assigning a function on the set of points of discontinuity.

Then, we can conclude that
$$
\lvert C \rvert \le \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert \cdot \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert
\cdot \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert \cdot \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert =
\lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert.
$$

Am I right here?

Comment: Simmons, in "Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis"  calls it  the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem. Engelking, in "General Topolgy" (in a hint to an exercise) calls it Cantor-Bernstein.  Elsewhere I have seen it called C-S-B.

Comment: @user254665 I added a link to the Wikipedia entry. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose four things:

1. A point of discontinuity $x_0$
2. A continuous function on $(-\infty, x_0)$
3. A continuous function on $(x_0,\infty)$
4. A function value at $x_0$

For each of these, you have $|\Bbb R|$ options to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Should I motivate points (2) and (3) using the same argument I did use with continuous real-valued functions? (i.e. equality on rationals implies equality on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @FilippoDeBortoli You could do that. You could also give an explicit bijection $C(-\infty, x_0) \to C(\Bbb R)$ by using some homeomorphism between $(-\infty, x_0)$ and $\Bbb R$, for instance $\log(x_0-x)$.